# Chosen jquery library not working when copy and append to another row

Tags: html, jquery, select, clone, jquery-chosen

In a table, I have 1 row with two multiple select tag in different cell. Both are using chosen Jquery library, I want to clone the row when user click on "Add Row" and append to the same table.

But, the Chosen Jquery library is not working in the cloned row. It have add the chosen tags, but is not showing in the browser.

Edit: This is my function where I clone the row and append to the same table at the last row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});

function addRow() {
  $("#item_table tbody tr:last").clone().appendTo($("#item_table tbody"));
    $("#item_table tbody tr:last .chosen-select").chosen();
    $("#item_table tbody tr:last .chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
  <table id="item_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Day</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="day" multiple class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Please select">
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            <option value="7">Sunday</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please add HTML and working demo so it was easy to find the issue and solve it.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I have added the HTML and working demo. please help. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For work Dropdown, you just need to create a unique id of each element before the clone

```
 clone.find("#select"+prev).attr("id", "select"+i);
```

and for remove previous selected clone record

```
clone.find("#select"+prev+"_chosen").attr("id", "select"+i+"_chosen1");
document.getElementById("select"+i+"_chosen1").outerHTML=""
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select0").chosen();
});
var i=1;
var prev =0;
function addRow() {
 var clone = $("#item_table tbody tr:last").clone()
 clone.find("#txtinput"+prev).attr("id", "txtinput"+i);
             clone.find("#select"+prev).attr("id", "select"+i);
            clone.find("#select"+prev+"_chosen").attr("id", "select"+i+"_chosen1");
 clone.appendTo($("#item_table tbody"));
document.getElementById("select"+i+"_chosen1").outerHTML=""
$myid = $('#select' + i);
$myid.show().chosen();
     i++;
     prev++;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
  <table id="item_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Day</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" id="txtinput0" /></td>
        <td>
          <select name="day" multiple class="chosen-select" id="select0" data-placeholder="Please select">
            <option value="1">Monday</option>
            <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
            <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="4">Thursday</option>
            <option value="5">Friday</option>
            <option value="6">Saturday</option>
            <option value="7">Sunday</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it solve my problem.